# When I save form data on a Joomla site to the database, Joomla logs me out

Tags: php, form, user-registration

I am trying to make a Joomla-based warranty registration system. Recently, I was able to turn on the possibility of registering new users and logging them in. Only registered/logged-in users will be able to register the warranty.

Data from the guarantee registration form are to be saved in the database.

However, when I try to register the guarantee with a logged-in user, the website logs me out by itself and nothing is saved to the database.

Why is this happening and what can I do to improve the operation of the website?

https://flaex-elektronarzedzia.pl/gwarancje2/

Comment: Welcome to JSE Adrian, please take our [tour].  Do you mean to use "warranty" and "guarantee" interchangeably?  I guess it is not important to your issue anyhow.  Please try to encapsulate the details of your question statically in your question.  Think about it, after your issue is fixed, the link to your website will no longer present the issue.  If you want to create a couple of small screenshots, it may be appropriate for this case.

Comment: The website in the link in the original post is not found, neither is the domain.